# Security testing - functional or non-functioal, ISO 9126 vs ISO 25010

Tags: security-testing, standards, istqb

Some sources, e.g. ISTQB, claim that security testig is a functional one. This would be compliant with ISO 9126 (which the ISTQB is based on) but it goes against most other sources - as far as I know, security is a non functional requirement. In ISO 25010, security is one of the quality characteristics (non functional).

I believe security testing is non functional testing as we do not test functionality, we examine the system from this perspective the same way we test performance.

Comment: Is there a question you want to ask and have answered? The way this is written it comes off as a statement. Is this a question that can be answered in a non-subjective way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISO 25010 is an [updated revision](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=22749) of ISO 9126. Security is considered [non-functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_testing).